# Regex - Single Char Prefix For Numbers

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

i have little bit struggled to obtain a regex.
this the case.

**Valid Case**

1. F33434343
2. 123243434333

**Invalid Case**

3. ABC23232
4. C2242422342

means only `F` can be a prefix, otherwise it only should be a number.

i tried `^([F]|[0-9]+)$` this, but its not helping. please suggest some idea or a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: "but its not helping" - in what way? What goes wrong with it? Please provide a [mcve] which shows that attempt and how it fails. (Wiktor has provided an answer, but please take this opportunity to improve your question, and as a learning experience for future questions.)

Comment: its saying first valid case also invalid

Comment: So state that in your question, ideally with a [mcve].

Comment: ok sure, i will improve, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make `F` optional before matching 1 or more digits:

```
^F?[0-9]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwPX15/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `matches()`)
- `F?` - an optional `F` char
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string anchor (implicit in `matches()`).

In Java, if you use `matches()`, you may even omit the leading `^` and trailing `$` anchors:

```
s.matches("F?[0-9]+")
```

Comment: thanks, its working,
can i use `^([F][0-9]+|[0-9]+)$`
is it also seems working, any defects in this regex.
but your is shorter, i will prefer yours.

Comment: @subash How did you arrive at such a pattern? It cannot work because after the end of string, you cannot expect any digits (and you require at least one with `[0-9]+`).

Comment: @subash `^([F][0-9]+|[0-9]+)$` is fine to use, but `^F?[0-9]+$` will yield the same result, is more readable and efficient due to the absence of alternation operator.